# books / examples / tutorials for Kinetic Kame

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

As a new learner to ROS I haven't seen literature such as books for Kinetic Kame, I'm interested in the Ros by Example book specifically but it is for Indigo.  Is it ok to use it for Kinetic Kame?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237714/books-/-examples-/-tutorials-for-kinetic-kame/) by [perigaacticon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27072/perigaacticon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some small changes between distributions. Each rosdistro has a Migration guide. Like [kinetic/Migration](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration) so you can know about big things that changed.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is OK to use older books, most of the concepts are similar. Moreover, you're likely not going to find a book specifically working w Kame for quite some time (Kame was released two months ago). Simply because this is open source software, ROS has a new release every year and there's not too many authors who have the time to churn out books.

There's a [ROS books wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Books) page though, that keeps a (hopefully updated) list of books. Personally, I like #1 and #2 that I've mentioned in my answer to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9797/are-there-any-books-on-ros/?answer=196847#post-id-196847).

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1